# What are the established methods for filing and tracking bugs in packages?

Tags: package-writing, documentclass-writing, polyglossia

My particular concern is in finding Polyglossia's author, Francois Charette, whose email address I could not find in Google. However, I think the issue is much more general.

If you encounter a bug in one of the packages you use, or something you believe is a bug, what are your options?

Comment: In this case, his email address is in the source: `Copyright (C) 2010 by François Charette <firmicus ατ gmx δοτ net>`. However, I think this is still a good question in general.

Comment: Does this mean that the "established" method for discussing bugs is contacting the author directly? No launchpad/bugzilla etc.?

Comment: Each (La)TeX package is independent, and so the contact method depends on the author. So for LaTeX itself (the kernel) you can use the LaTeX Project bugs database. Some authors have webpages/bug databases, others do not. That's up to them, as they set the license for their code, the distribution method, _etc_. For my own packages, I do have public bug databases, but most of the bug reports are either by e-mail or things I spot in various web forums (here, c.t.t, the LaTeX Community, _etc_.)

Comment: Polyglossia's issue tracker is on github: https://github.com/fc7/polyglossia/issues

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I try following things in the following order:

1. look into the manual for the email address of the maintainer and the preferred bug-reporting protocol
2. google the project homepage and look for further information of bug reporting/contact data
3. look at the source files of the package
4. ask at the usenet/mailinglists/tex.stackexchange for suggestions